# D3 put times in X axis instead of array value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This question is a bit tricky. I have some example code working with the following data. It plots it on a line graph.

```
var dataset = [{
      y: 0.1
    },
    {
      y: 0.6
    },
        {
      y: 0.6
    },
    {
      y: 0.7
    }
  ];
```

D3 uses the following code to put this on the X axis:

```
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
.domain([0, n - 1]) // input
.range([0, width]); // output
```

However I'm really looking to get dat

```
var dataset = [{
      "1pm": 0.1
    },
    {
      "2pm": 0.6
    },
        {
      "3pm": 0.6
    },
    {
      "4pm": 0.7
    }
  ];
```

How do I put these values into the graph X axis instead of it just being based on the array numbers? When I try the code as it is above it breaks the graph it says:

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "M0,NaNC17.222222222…".
```

This is the full code:

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/e6hv9x8m/17/

Comment: So in your example, you're looking to have the key of the property in your dataset objects be the x value, and the value of the property in your dataset objects be the y value? Or are you just looking for a way to format the ticks?

Comment: @DannyBuonocore In my old example, it uses the key of the property as the X value, correct. However, I want to plot values against time, so I want my X axit to be time values. Therefore I replaced the "y" in the data with the value I want for the X axis, but I can't display this text on the x axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6hv9x8m/20/).

First off, you can include an additional value in your dataset objects to represent the x value, I've called this `date`:

```
var dataset = [{
    y: 0.1,
    date: new Date(2012,0,1)
  },
  {
    y: 0.6,
    date: new Date(2012,0,2)
  }
];
```

Next, the x scale needs to be changed from linear to time:

```
var minDate = new Date(2012,0,1);
var maxDate = new Date(2012,0,2);

var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([minDate, maxDate])
  .range([0, width]);
```

And finally, you must update the callback here to pull the `date` field from the dataset object, rather than just it's position in the array:

```
var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d, i) {
    return xScale(d.date);
  }) // set the x values for the line generator
  .y(function(d) {
    return yScale(d.y);
  }) // set the y values for the line generator 
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX) // apply smoothing to the line
```

Comment: Thank you very much